# Как уменьшить время ответа request в node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

Доброго времени суток!

Делаю бота для торговой площадки, который через сокет сканирует новые, добавленные вещи и скупает их если название и цена совпадают с теми что я указываю, все вроде работает, но бот не успевает купить вещь, так как проходит слишком много времени (порядка 250-300мс), не хитрым кодом я проверил время выполнения скрипта и понял что во всем виновата функция парсинга информации о вещи. Найти решение мне так и не удалось, пробовал найти альтернативу request, но не вышло. Вся надежда на вас

PS. Пробую открыть ссылку из функции в браузере, консоль показывает время выполнения 100-180мс.

Функция парсинга информации:

```
function getItemsInfo( classid, instanceid, infoCallback ) {
    var rOptions = {
        url: 'https://market.csgo.com/api/ItemInfo/' +classid+ '_' +instanceid+ '/ru/?key=' +apiKey
    };
    request( rOptions, function( err, resp, body ) {
        if( err && resp.statusCode !== 200 ) {
            loggerMess( 'Ошибка!: ' +resp.err, 'error' );
            return;
        }
        if( typeof( body ) === 'string' ) {
            fs.writeFileSync( 'logs/error_getItemsInfo.txt', body );
            infoCallback( JSON.parse( body ) );
        }
    } );
}
```

```
function newItems( data ) {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    if( typeof( data ) === 'string' ) {
        data = JSON.parse( data );  
        var objData = JSON.parse( data.data );
    }
    var app = objData.app;
    if( app == 'go' ) {
        var market_hash_name = objData.i_market_hash_name;
        var classid = objData.i_classid;
        var instanceid = objData.i_instanceid;
        var uiprice = objData.ui_price; 
        for( items in OrderItems ) {
            //console.log( items );
            if( market_hash_name === OrderItems[items].name && uiprice <= OrderItems[items].price ) {
                var OItemsName = OrderItems[items].name;
                var OItemsPrice = OrderItems[items].price;
                var OItemsAutobuy = OrderItems[items].autobuy;
                getItemsInfo( classid, instanceid, function( info ) {
                    //console.log( info );
                    if( info.stickers != null ) {
                        var stickerNum = info.stickers.split( '|' );
                        if( stickerNum.length >= 1 && stickerNum.length <= 3 ) {
                            if( OItemsAutobuy === 'yes' ) {
                                buyItems( classid, instanceid, uiprice, info.hash );
                            }
                            console.log( 'M: ' +market_hash_name+ ' (' +uiprice+ ') - O: ' +OItemsName+ ' S: ' +stickerNum.length+ ' A: ' +OItemsAutobuy );
                            console.log( 'https://market.csgo.com/item/' +classid+ '-' +instanceid );
                        } else if( stickerNum.length == 4 ) {
                            buyItems( classid, instanceid, uiprice, info.hash );
                            console.log( 'M: ' +market_hash_name+ ' (' +uiprice+ ' ) - O: ' +OItemsName+ ' S: ' +stickerNum.length+ ' A: ' +OItemsAutobuy );
                            console.log( 'https://market.csgo.com/item/' +classid+ '-' +instanceid );
                        }
                        var resTime = new Date().getTime() - time;
                        loggerMess( resTime, 'info' );
                        //if( soundAlert ) { console.log( '\x07' ); }                       
                    }
                } );
            }
            if( purchased ) {
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: 1. _"и понял что во всем виновата функция парсинга информации о вещи"_ - ну так её и надо было показывать. 2. Мне кажется, что наличие `fs.writeFileSync` гораздо более виновато. 3. http-запрос - это не сокеты.

Comment: Выше же эта функция.
fs.writeFileSync - без него тоже самое, добавил я ее для отлова html документа что бы сделать проверку на ошибку при использовании JSON.parse.
Я знаю что не сокеты, суть в чем, бот, подключается через WebSocket к wss (апи торговой площадки), от туда получает данные типа string, потом парсит их в json-obj и уже сверяет с моим массивом (имя, цена и т.д) если совпало, то отправляется уже http-запрос для получения полной информации, если все подходит, то происходит покупка вещи.
И вот он не успевает купить так как проходит много времени.

Comment: Скорее всего у тебя неэффективный алгоритм проверки надо покупать вещь, или нет.

Comment: Вот основная функция где должна "твориться магия" - https://pastebin.com/vb5vrU7G 
Что тут не так?

Answer (score 1):

Убери  `fs.writeFileSync` и `if typeof`, поставь `try catch`, замерь время. 
Убери  запрос на ItemInfo, тебе от куда нужно только hash, сделай разовые запросы для каждого предмета из твоего списка предметов и занеси в массив под каждый предмет. 
Hash не меняется со временем, он статичен и уникален для каждого предмета. 
Так что не вижу смысла каждый раз просить его.

Я как писал бота для отправки предметов, перед покупкой я проверял в соответствующей таблицу есть ли у меня для этого предмета hash, если не было, отправлял запрос и заносил в бд. Таким образом сокращал кол. обращений на csgo.tm

Увидел что ты добавил еще код. Убери console.log - он выполняется синхронно, используй вместо него какой-то асинхронный вывод. Пример: winston

Comment: try catch - так себе совет. try-catch не оптимизируется, точнее, не оптимизировался до недавнего времени.

Comment: Разве у одинакового оружия с разными стикерами, hash не меняется?

Comment: @Бесенок, На сколько я помню classId и instanceId меняется вместе со стикерами

Comment: @Qwertiy, разве `try catch` хуже чем писать в файл ? Можно погуглить другие проверки на валидность JSON

Comment: Так мне в любом случае нужно посылать запрос к ItemInfo что бы узнать есть ли на оружке стикер или нет

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан, не надо ни то, ни другое - ни файлов, ни try-catch'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy, скрипт же упадет, зачем ему жрать авто перезапуска демоном ? Поправь, если я где-то не прав. Если решение по лучше ?

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан, во-первых, в приведённом автором варианте он тоже упадёт - возможно, его это в данный момент устраивает. Во-вторых, сначала надо настроить, чтобы он вообще работал так, как надо, а потом уже разбираться с падениями. И если добавлять try-catch, то лучше вынести это в отдельную функцию, потому что неизвестно, какую версию nodejs он использует. Если у него весь код в одной функции и она вся окажется неоптимизируемой, то это плохо.

Comment: То вы против `try catch`, то решение с ним предлагаете :)

Comment: Я точно ничего не понимаю, создал пустой "проект", подключил модуль request, создал функцию и тут же ее запускаю и получаю 300+мс...

`function buyItems( classid, instanceid ) {
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 request( 'https://market.csgo.com/api/GetItemDescription/'+classid+'_'+instanceid+'/?key=' +apiKey, function( err, resp, body ) { 
  if( err && resp.statusCode !== 200 ) {
   console.log( resp.error );
   return; 
  }
  //body = JSON.parse( body );
  var resTime = new Date().getTime() - time;
  console.log( 'Time: ' +resTime );
 } ); 
}

buyItems( '549260619', '0' );`

Comment: @Бесенок, а вы думали за 1 мс получите ответ ?! Сам csgo.tm может долго обрабатывать запрос.

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан Я это понимаю, но дело то в том что, открываю эту же ссылку в браузере и консоль показывает 100-150мс

Comment: @Бесенок, сделайте просто request на эту ссылку без лишнего кода, чтобы единственное что присутствовало, это счетчик времени. И посмотрите на результат, если и таким образом мс не достигнет нужного параметра, то видимо проблема уже не в алгоритме.

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан К сожалению ничего не поменялось :( Хотел еще уточнить по поводу Вашей идеи с сохранением хеша, можно поподробней? как это будет сравниваться или же с небольшим примером, а то, что то я не могу сообразить как все это будет выглядеть. Если подумать, то сохраняя хеш в бд, потом можно работать с ним "локально" не отправляя http-запрос, а так как я в виду своей невнимательности пропустил тот факт что в ответе сокета приходит информация о стикерах, отпадает надобность получать стикеры из iteminfo, а значит что нужно будет использовать только один http-запрос на покупку вещи.

Answer (score 0):

1. Убери `fs.writeFileSync`
2. Замени `for( items in OrderItems ) {` на нормальный цикл
3. Не вижу, чтобы коллбэк `getItemsInfo` как-то использовал item (кроме критерия покупать или нет, что вообще странно) - вероятно, его не надо делать в цикле.
4. Замени `new Date()` на `performance.now()`.